# How can i retrieve all data and insert into sql from DataGridView

Tags: c#

i want to retrieve all cell and row from dataGridView and pase in textbox or label,or insert into sql server

i tried to use this

```
 string value;
    public void getGridData()
    {
          foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {

               foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
               {
                   value = cell.Value.ToString();
                   //MessageBox.Show(value);
                   textBox1.Text = value;


               }

           }

    }
```

when i  user MessaBox.show it works,but in textBoxt nope, please help me

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint, debug and tell what kind of values do you receive?

Comment: i retrieve only last value of cell and without try it tells me  NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you keep overwriting the textbox.

Maybe *appending* to the textbox is what you need:  `textBox1.Text += value;`